# Error: Unexpected field Amazon S3, Express, Multer, MulterS3

Tags: express, aws-sdk, multer, multer-s3

I am getting this error and I have no idea why its giving me that error, I have checked all the tutorials/similar questions related to this and nothing has worked. Can someone please help point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

**Error:**

Unexpected field

Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\express-cc-master\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\express-cc-master\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)

**Profile.js**

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk')
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer')
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3')

 
aws.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
aws.config.update({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
 
var s3 = new aws.S3({});

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'raytestbucket123',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now()+file.originalname)
    }
  })
})

router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
  res.render('profile', { title: 'Profile' });

});


router.post('/profile', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next){

  res.send(req.files);
  console.log(req.files);

})


module.exports = router;
```

**Profile.hbs**

```html
{{> header }}



  <body> 
    <form action="/profile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      File to upload to S3: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
    </form> 
  </body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Profile</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.

Instead of

res.send(req.files);
  console.log(req.files);

It  should be

res.send(req.file);
  console.log(req.file);